# Can you set limits for Google cloud API authorizarion

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to set the credentials for google sheet and google drive authentication but for only 1 specific spreadsheet or folder, I don't know if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

According to this method:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

The deeper element that you can have access is the sheet. I think it is not possible to change this scope since the authentication/authorization is made around all the service and the API.